# sql query to remove "/" slash from a record

Tags: mysql, database

I have some entries in my database that I want to clean from slash char, like this:

```
text-/-moreText
```

I want to upgrade to:

```
text-moreText
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `column` LIKE BINARY '%\/%'
```

This query works with chars like: , but it doesn't with /

Answer (score 0):

[replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) should be able to do it

```
update 
myTable
set col = replace(col,'/','');


mysql> select replace('text-/-moreText','/','');
+-----------------------------------+
| replace('text-/-moreText','/','') |
+-----------------------------------+
| text--moreText                    |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace('text--moreText','/','');
+----------------------------------+
| replace('text--moreText','/','') |
+----------------------------------+
| text--moreText                   |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: well yes, that is how you can do if you have one entry in your DB but if you have multiple entry? I need to use where clausal to change multiple entries but how? LIKE BINARY '%\/%' doesn't work.

Comment: The above statement will update the entire table not just one value.